# SQL. Подзапросы. В чем ошибка (вывод всех продавцов, которые продали больше чем продавец N)?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, запрос, запрос-в-запросе

Есть  таблица SALES c полями:

- `ID_SALE` - ID продажи
- `name_good` - название товара
- `date_sale` - дата продажи
- `FIO_saler` -ФИО продавца
- `price`- цена товара

Нужно вывести всех продавцов, которые продали больше чем продавец `“Иванов Иван”` (записи с таким продавцом должны быть) за май 2015.

Вопрос: почему возникает ошибка, как её исправить, чтобы выводилась нужная информация?

```
 select FIO_saler,price
  from sales
 where sum(price)> all
    (SELECT price
     from sales
     where FIO_saler='Иванов Иван Иванович' 
    );
    /
```

Comment: Во первых функцию sum нельзя использовать в where, ее можно и нужно использовать только в having, который работает после группировки. Во вторых вам видимо надо как то сгруппировать sales по продавцам (с помощью group by). И в третьих вы сейчас выбираете такие суммы которые больше не суммы продаж Иванова, а больше отдельных его продаж. в подзапросе видимо надо так же использовать sum

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду знать теперь!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT FIO_saler, 
       SUM(price) AS summa
FROM   sales
WHERE  date_sale > '2015-12-23' 
AND    date_sale < '2015-12-31'
GROUP  BY FIO_saler
HAVING SUM(price) > (SELECT SUM(price) FROM sales WHERE FIO_saler='Иванов Иван Иванович');
```

[Проверка](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf5b2/6)

Comment: Отличное оформление. Тоже пользуюсь этим ресурсом для проверки запросов, но давать ссылки на настроенные примеры не додумался. Возьму на вооружение.

Comment: Большоооое Вам спааасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT FIO_saler,
       price 
FROM   SALES 
WHERE  FIO_saler IN 
        (SELECT FIO_saler 
         FROM   SALES 
         GROUP  BY FIO_saler
         HAVING SUM(PRICE) > (SELECT SUM(price) 
                              FROM   SALES 
                              WHERE FIO_saler = 'Иванов Иван Иванович')
      )
AND   date_sale BETWEEN _Начало_ AND _Конец_
```

Вам остается только наложить условие на период продажи вместо `_Начало_` и `_Конец_` в соответствии с типом данных поля.

Comment: Большое спасибо!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!